# Nested for loops where inner loops are dependent on outer ones

Tags: python, python-3.x, standard-library

Consider the following problem:

> Sum some function f : Z^2 -> R over all positive integers (x,y), where x, y are in [0, B]

This is rather easy to implement in Python:

```
res = 0
for x in range(B+1):
    for y in range(B+1):
        res += f(x,y)
```

Of course, there are many "better" ways you can write the above statement. I'll focus on a specific method --- using itertools, you can specifically write:

```
res = 0
for vals in itertools.product(range(B+1), repeat = 2)
    res += f(*vals)
```

This has the benefit that it makes generalizing it to functions f : Z^n -> R trivial, just change `repeat = 2` to `repeat = n`. If the variables have different ranges, you change the code to `itertools.product(*[B1, B2, ..., Bn])`, again quite easy.

---

I'm interested in doing the above, but where the variables I'm summing over are "dependent" in a certain way.
It's enough to consider the case where I'm summing over the variables (x,y) in [0, B]^2 where x + y <= B.

You can again write this as a nested for loop:

```
res = 0
for x in range(B):
    for y in range(B - x):
        res += f(x, y)
```

I'm interested if there's any standard library methods to generalize this (just like how `itertools.product` generalized the last construction). You could use the iterator.product construction again (and just `pass` when the (x1, x2, ..., xn) don't fit the criterion), but I was wondering if there was a more direct way of iterating over this set using the standard library.

The reason that the `pass`ing approach is unsuitable is because of the number of points you'll have to pass over. Some mathematical computations (relating the volume of the unit l1 ball to the volume of the unit l infinity ball as a function of dimension) shows that only 1 / n! points will meet the acceptance criteria, so there will be a quite large "waste" in iterating over [0, B]^n, and checking if some criteria is true.

Comment: I am not sure why you want a library method when all you need is `if x + y > B: continue` (or, in general, `if not cond(*vals): continue`). Please explain. In fact, the most general (but not the most efficient) solution is `sum(f(*vals) for vals in product(range(B+1), repeat = 2) if cond(*vals))`.

Comment: Maybe [`itertools.filterfalse()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.filterfalse) is what you want?

Comment: @DYZ It's mostly because of the extra points you iterate over. Each iteration will be quite fast, but the number of points that satisfy the condition becomes quite small as n gets large. The math is kind of esoteric (the ratio of the volume of the unit l1 ball in the unit l-infinity ball as a function of dimension), but only a fraction of 1 / n! points will satisfy the check.

This means you're iterating over roughly n! too many points, which seems not great.

Comment: You may want to add this remark to your question.